# What is the URL header used for in AWS API GET request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, get

I am looking at example AWS STS API request calls like below from the AWS web page

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: sts.amazonaws.com
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
URL: https://sts.amazonaws.com/?DurationS .......
```

I can't seem to understand if the URL HTTP Header is a custom header used only by AWS or if its something new in HTTP (like with CORS)

Either way I could not find any reference to this Header.

Can someone please explain what this header is ? (i.e custom to AWS or something more general)

Comment: Where did you find it? It's not even in API docs.

Comment: FWIW, the content type is broken - there is no charset parameter on application/json

Comment: Please provide a link to the documentation in question.

Comment: Sorry I should have provided the link in the original question. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WIF.RunningYourApp.html

This could just be a case of an error in the docs, because the API docs for this API call in the example (AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity) has the "correct"  HTTP get request format. (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html)